# ¿Cómo partir una tabla en dos partes y aplicarles "UNION"?

Tags: r

Tengo la siguiente consigna para resolver. Pensaba en partirla por ejemplo con sample(iris$Sepal.Length,75), pero no sabría como unir despues las partes y partir la tabla y no solo un vector.

### Parte iris en dos partes iguales (75 observaciones cada uno) con las filas elegidas al azar ## (¡y complementarias!).

Answer (score 1):

La forma más sencilla es "randomizar" un vector de lógicos con igual proporción de verdaderos y falsos, de esta forma aprovechamos la selección mediante lógicos:

```
seleccionados <- sample(rep(TRUE:FALSE, nrow(iris)), replace = TRUE) 

iris[seleccionados,]  # Los seleccionados
iris[!seleccionados,] # El complemento de los seleccionados
```